# How to ignore RAW files in DigiKam

Tags: digikam

All my photos are in one directory tree:

```
pics/
  |--<timestamp>-<name>/  # contains exported jpgs/heifs
  |        |-- raw/       # contains RAWS & SOOCs
```

After I'm done with modifying the RAWs, I'll delete the SOOCs. I'd like DigiKam to only work with jpgs/heifs (because the RAWs are not meant for "viewing pleasure"). How can I tell DigiKam to "not import"/"ignore" RAW files?
Neither do I want to search those, nor do I want any face detection to be run on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for "digikam ignore folder" on the web I found a [blog post](https://scribblesandsnaps.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/quick-tip-disable-certain-file-types-in-digikam/) with a tip on how to disable file types in digikam:

> Choose **Settings →View** digiKam and switch to the **MIME Types** section. To exclude, for example, the PPM format, enter *-ppm* in the **Image Files** field.

In your case you would enter the file extension of your RAW files (e.g. `CR2` or `DNG`).

Also note the warning in the blog post (bolding mine):

> Excluding specific formats from digiKam doesn’t actually delete them, but simply hides them from digiKam and **removes all metadata from the digiKam databases. So be careful when using exclusion filters if you don’t want to lose tags, ratings, and other metadata**.

The MIME Types functionality is also mention on [page 112 of the manual](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/digikam-doc/digikam/digikam.pdf#page=112).

I don't use digikam myself, I just found this information on Google, so I cannot guarantee this works.

Comment: I found this blog post as well. Sadly it's from 2011 and DigiKam does not have a group "MIME-Type" in its settings now.

Comment: har! It's now located under settings / views / mime types!
Thanks for the hint (the online-manual was not searchable and I wasn't aware of the PDF version existing).

Comment: "I found this blog post as well" ... and that's why it's always asked that you [include your research in your question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That saves volunteers time in re-iterating unhelpful advice.